# My banner is not visible in Safari 5.1.7

Tags: css, cross-browser, banner

[This page](http://www.fantasylab.no) I am developing has a different layout on Safari than Chrome/Firefox

- [Here is how it looks in Safari](http://prntscr.com/7rofxm)
- [Here is how it looks in Firefox](http://prntscr.com/7rog3z)

As you can see, the top banner isn't showing on Safari and i think it's because of the parallax CSS I have added for the banner if I'm not completely wrong here.

Here is the CSS:

```
.slide {
    position: relative;
    padding: 15vh 1%;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
    transform-style: inherit;
}

.slide:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
}

.title {
    width: 50%;
    padding: 5%;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(240,230,220, .7);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7);
}

.slide:nth-child(2n) .title {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.slide:nth-child(2n+1) .title {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 0;
}

.slide, .slide:before {
    background: 50% 50% / cover;  
}

#title {
    background-image: url("http://bildeopplaster.no/8Kk");
    background-attachment: fixed;  
}

.carsonshold { position: relative; width: 100%; display: block; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; }
.carsonshold img { padding: 20px; display: block; border: none; }
#thesedays { padding: 10px 20px; margin: 40px 0; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccc; }
#results { padding: 10px 20px; background: #fff; border: 1px solid #ccc; font-family: monospace; }

.text-link {
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 0.85em;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Can anyone see why the banner isn't showing up on Safari or what am I missing here?

Comment: Can reproduce in Safari 7.1.7, what version are you using?

Comment: I am using Safari 5.1.7 on Windows. Could you please send me a screen show on how it looks like on your Safari browser please? Thanks!

Comment: I'm guessing you are using Safari for Windows, which is obsolete. Apple abandoned it a while ago, and I doubt many people actually use it. Here's a screenshot anyway: https://i.imgur.com/Fsj8COk.jpg

Comment: @NohmanJ 5.1.7 is the last version for Windows, but they are much further along in versions for OS X. It's possible there is a feature you are using that Safari 5.1.7 doesn't support. Like `background: 50% 50% / cover;`. Safari didn't support `background-position` until version 7. This is a non-issue, though, really, because nobody on Windows will be using Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first issue is you are using `vh` units for that element. Unfortunately, Safari didn't support `vh` and `vw` units until Version 6 (unprefixed in Version 6.1).

The second issue is that you are using the `background: 50% 50% / cover;` property-value pair. That is also not a supported value in Safari 5.1.7. You need to remove the `/ cover` bit for it to work in Safari 5.1.7. Safari 5.1.7 *should* support `background-size: cover;`, but it seems like it doesn't support the shorthand version you're trying to use here.

Using these values will fix it, more or less:

```
.slide, .slide::before {
    background: 50% 50%;
}

.slide {
    padding: 15%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**With that being said**, this shouldn't be an issue, because people who use Safari as their main browser will probably be on OS X, which means they'll be on a newer version of Safari. It's unlikely anyone will be using Safari on Windows for their main browser. Then again, it's possible, considering there are still Opera 12 users out there...